# How do you make Seahorse (Gnome Keyring) store passwords for ssh keys in?

Tags: 11.10, ssh, gnome-keyring, seahorse

I'm trying to get Seahorse to remember the password for an existing RSA key I've copied across from another computer.

When I use the key rather than Gnome Keyring prompting me for the password and storing it on the keyring I have to enter the password in terminal and the password isn't remembered?

How do I use Seahorse to save my SSH key password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved, needed to add the key to be used for each particular machine.

Can do this by going to,

Gnome Keyring -> My Personal Keys -> Right click on key -> Configure key for secure shell

Answer (score 5):

You can also use ssh-add to add the key to the keyring. (This one worked for me whereas the "Configure key..." did not.)

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ssh-agent` that remembers your ssh passwords, e.g. https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Ssh

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.